# Android Studio:Genymotion error:cannot find genymotion in the specified path

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

My operating system is Windows 7 Ultimate. I've downloaded and installed Genymotion from it's official website, and I've also installed the plugin in Android Studio. Meanwhile, I've set SDK in Genymotion. However, I am getting an error when I enter the path of Genymotion in Android Studio.

Please find the screenshot below.
[image: Error Screenshot]
I've also browsed some websites, is it possible that the plugin version is too low ?
How can I solve this problem ?